# Getting error in SQL Server while running this SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Please find the SQL query I'm running here - I am not able to find out where is the mistake. In SQL server, it is pointing on the closing last closing brace. Please help.
Editing the sql which is now giving another error.
SELECT Crontaskname,
       Instancename,
       schedule,
       Lastrun
FROM (SELECT Crontaskname,
             Instancename,
             schedule,
             Lastrun,
             (CASE WHEN (((CASE (SUBSTRING(schedule,-(LEN(schedule)-(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)- 2)), 1))
                                 WHEN 's' THEN lastrun + (1/86400 * SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)-2)))+0.2
                                 WHEN 'm' THEN  lastrun + (1/1440 * SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)-2))) + 0.2 
                                 WHEN 'h' THEN  lastrun + (1/24 * SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)-2)))
                                 WHEN 'd' THEN  lastrun + SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)-2))
                                 WHEN 'w' THEN  lastrun + (7 * SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)-2)))
                                 WHEN 'M' THEN  DATEADD (MONTH, SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule, ',')-2)), lastrun)
                                 WHEN 'y' THEN  DATEADD (MONTH, 12*(SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule, ',')-2))), lastrun)
                            END) - getdate()) < 0)
                   THEN 'BAD'
                   ELSE 'GOOD'
              END) AS Status
       FROM (SELECT crontaskname,
                    instancename,
                    schedule,
                    (SELECT lastrun
                     FROM taskscheduler AS B
                     WHERE B.taskname = ISNULL(A.crontaskname, '')+'.'+ISNULL(A.instancename, '')  as lastrun
              FROM crontaskinstance AS A 
              WHERE instancename IN ('SEQQOUT_SYS_11','SEQQOUT_SYS_21','SEQQOUT_SYS_12')
                AND active = 1
                AND crontaskname <> 'REPORTSCHEDULE') AS X) AS Cron WHERE Status = 'BAD';

Comment: If you took the time format your code, I'm sure you'd find the error very quickly. :)

Comment: Well I've edited that mess (don't mean to be rude, but it really was). Couple of things I noticed, a `WHEN` without a `THEN`, and there are parenthesis that aren't closed. There's a lot of overuse of parenthesis as well (making your query hard to read), and the subquery don't help either and it doesn't look like it needs them either.

Comment: Oh, there's 2 `CASE` expressions in there (told you it was hard to read).

Comment: HEY MATE, PUT YOUR sql IN HERE AND IT highlights an error for you - that speeds up both things, formatting and checking http://poorsql.com/

Comment: there are many issue, multiple nested selects are not properly closed, inner cases are also not have parenthesis. your last closing parenthesis is not meeting opening as that is already another child :O

Comment: Tried poorsql.com also, not getting the correct format of sql. Poorsql is giving various different errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple issues.

- The table expression inside the table expression (the one with the SELECT query on the `crontaskinstance` table) does not have an alias... If I give it an alias, things seem to get parsed correctly.
- One of the WHEN-blocks in the inner CASE expression misses a closing parenthesis.
- Field `sysdate` is unknown.

That's as far as I got...

As @Larnu already said... You REALLY need to format the code to get these kinds of errors quicklier. Perhaps using CTE's might be helpful too.

Edit:

I went somewhat further. Got the error "Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 3 of charindex function." Here I give up reviewing this query. ;)

Comment: 2 - `WHEN 'd' THEN  lastrun + SUBSTRING(schedule,0,(CHARINDEX(',', schedule)-2)` > `)`

Comment: @DxTx Yes, that's the one.

Comment: I replaced sysdate with getdate(). Still getting an error. I am really not clear which of the nested when block does not have closing brace and where I need to give alias. Can you provide the aliased query? thanks for your help!

Comment: The last line in your query: the first closing parentheses closes a table expression. It has no alias. You probably want something like `AND crontaskname <> 'REPORTSCHEDULE') AS X) AS Cron WHERE Status = 'BAD';`...

Comment: Ye, I got you Bart! Thanks for helping. Now I am getting an error of rownum. Is there any equivalent in sqlsever which rownum in oracle sql. Below is the modified query.

Comment: For that, you may look into the ROW_NUMBER() function of SQL Server. It uses an additional OVER-clause in which you specify the record ordering for the numbering logic.

Comment: @BartHofland, I agree with you & @Larnu. This codes needs to be correctly scripted to easily find errors. However I also found (by just quickly looking) that the open bracket after `SELECT Crontaskname,
       Instancename,
       schedule,
       Lastrun
FROM` does not have a closing bracket. After this closing bracket, no alias is also specified.

Comment: @Birel It has. ;) It's that first closing parenthesis in the last line of the query. That's also the table expression I was referring to.